# Prime attribute dependant on another prime attribute allowed under BCNF?

Tags: database-theory, databases

I have been studying DBMS ans I have a question that I got conflicting answers to:
Is prime attribute that is dependant on another prime attribute allowed under BCNF?

Meaning P->P.

I know that NP->P is not allowed.
and also NP->NP (as it is not 3NF - transitive relation)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a relation is in BCNF if and only if, for every non trivial functional dependency, the left hand part is a candidate key.

So, if you have a dependency `A → B` where both A and B are prime attributes, this dependency violates the Normal Form only if A is not a candidate key, but a part of some candidate key.

Note that in that case, the dependency does not violates the 3NF.

Answer (score 0):

every determinant should be candidate key, so write down candidate keys, then write down functional dependencies. after that check whether  on the left hand side of '->' what you have, if all of them are candidate keys(whole candidate keys, not part of it) then it is in BCNF, otherwise it violates BCNF property, where every determinant should be candidate key.